# 2D vector Segments

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

I'm trying to split a massive vector into blocks using a 2D vector.

The problem is that when I run the program, I get a segmentation fault: 11 error. Here is the code:

```
vector< vector<double> > Audio::something(vector<double>& theData, int N, int M)
{
int n = theData.size();
int maxblockstart = n - N;
int lastblockstart = maxblockstart - (maxblockstart % M);

int numblocks = (lastblockstart)/M + 1;
vector< vector<double> > subBlock;
this->width = N;
this->height = numblocks;

for(int i=0; (i < numblocks); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; (j < N); j++)
    {   
        subBlock[i][j] = theData[i*N+j];
    } 
}

return subBlock;
}
```

What I was thinking is implementing a temp vector that stores the result of (theData[i*N+j]) and then pushing back inside the 2D vector, but, that doesn't work.. Any ideas? Thank you :)

P.S. Ignore the method name "something" it's just what I named it for testing purposes, I will change this once I have solved this problem!

Comment: you never tell the subBlock to have a size nor are you pushing stuff into it. resize the vector right before the loop

Comment: `subBlock` has no space allocated. You need to `resize` it first, or `push_back` your data. (Note you'll need to do this for all the internal `vector`s as well).

Comment: You could simplify your nested loop to just `for(int i = 0; i < numblocks; i++) subBlock.push_back(std::vector<double>(&theData[i * N], &theData[(i + 1) * N]));` by exploiting the fact that pointers into your `theData` array can be considered iterators, so you can use the `std::vector` constructor taking two iterators. The code might also benefit from a `subBlock.reserve(numblocks);` call before the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use method `push_back` to insert data into vector

```
for(int i=0; (i < numblocks); i++)
{
    subBlock.push_back(vector<double>());
    for(int j=0; (j < N); j++)
    {   
        subBlock[i].push_back(theData[i*N+j]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did this and it worked (Kinda) it just produces a lot of 0's at the end of the 2D vector when printing.. Have I resized it correctly? "    subBlock.resize(600*187);"

Comment: i have created 600*187 vector's if you need so much it's ok i guess, but better choose another method for this amount of elements

Answer (score 3):

This is one problem:

```
subBlock[i][j] = theData[i*N+j];
```

as `subBlock` was default constructed and therefore contains no entries. You need to add elements into the `subBlock` before using them. You can construct the vector with `numblocks` count of `vector<double>` each with `N` doubles using the following [`std::vector::vector()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) constructor:

```
vector<vector<double> > subBlock(numblocks, vector<double>(N));
```

and the `for` loop remains as is.